# Erlang Common Test: Get test runtime stats across all test suites

Tags: unit-testing, testing, erlang, common-test

I currently have a set of applications, each with their own set of test suites. Is there a way to get test case runtimes in a when running one or more CT test suites?

I know the test reports provide the testcase runtimes, but they aren't available in a format that I can easily parse in my script that will output test runtime statistics. I want to be able to get some raw data on the runtimes for all test cases. JSON, XML, or CSV would be fine. I do not want to parse the raw HTML to get the test runtimes.

Are there any existing tools (CT hooks?) that do something like this already? I feel like it shouldn't be too hard, but I'm not finding any existing software that does this.

Comment: Yes, there is. http://erlang.org/doc/man/ct_hooks.html

Comment: @Pouriya I'm aware of CT hooks in general. That page doesn't have anything on an existing CT hook implementation that collects this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like this can be done with the `cth_surefire` Common Test hook. The CT hook produces junit XML output, which contains the test run times. All I need to do is parse out the test names and times to compute the statistics I need.

See these pages for more details:

- https://marcelog.github.io/articles/erlang_test_report_in_junit_format_common_test_publish_jenkins.html
- https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/11908525cfd1f048296ef3718a367d7c34e7cdb4